# Create PDF for each pivot filter

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, pivot

I currently have a pivot table which created a statement of outstanding invoices, which is filtered by account name. I would like to create a macro where excel makes a PDF statement for each account.

I have no knowledge of VBA so I got the code below by searching google and edited it for my pivot table.

However when I try to run it excel does not like this line “.CurrentPage = pi.Name”. When I take this out it does run and created several PDFs with the correct account name, but all the statements are the same just.

Is anyone able to help?

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim strPath As String
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

Set wksSource = Worksheets("AP Pivot")

Set PT = wksSource.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Set pf = PT.PivotFields("ACCOUNT")

If pf.Orientation <> xlPageField Then
MsgBox "There's no 'ACCOUNT' field in the Report Filter. Try again!", vbExclamation
Exit Sub
End If

strPath = "T:\"

If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

PT.PivotCache.Refresh

With pf
.ClearAllFilters
For Each pi In .PivotItems
.CurrentPage = pi.Name
wksSource.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & pi.Name & ".pdf"
Next pi
.ClearAllFilters
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message that line throws?

Comment: One problem you might be having is that the pivot items collection of your "account" - field still has values in it which no longer exist in your data. Does it work when you add `pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone` just before `PT.PivotCache.Refresh`?

Comment: Adding that line has done it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that the pivot items collection of your "Account" field still has values in it which no longer exist in your data. So your filter is being set to a value which isn't available. To fix this you van add `pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone` just before `PT.PivotCache.Refresh`.

This deletes all missing items from your pivot items collection.